# trim a string containing time from date picker

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, date

I am using angular UI date picker to get the date. I save the date into a string variable. The problem is that I want the date to be trimmed out in a very specific format. I don't know regex, at all which I think is the right way to do this in javascript? Can somebody tell me the regex that I can write in a function that will trim the input to the specific output using native javascript only. 
e.g.
Input:

> Thursday sep 20-2-2015 00:00:00 GMT (+5:00) Pakistan Standard Time.

Output should be:

> 20-2-2015 00:00:00.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you do not need regex for this, did you try giving a look to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date

Comment: The example uses the getDate method which i believe gets the current date only? what about if i chose the date randomly using a date picker then i dont this would work? Also it doesn't answers about the time  hh:mm:ss that i want too. Or maybe i have missed something on that link?

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script language=javascript>
      var txt='Thursday sep 20-2-2015 00:00:00 GMT (+5:00) Pakistan Standard Time';

      var re1='.*?';  // Non-greedy match on filler
      var re2='(20-2-2015)';  // DDMMYYYY 1
      var re3='(\\s+)'; // White Space 1
      var re4='(00:00:00)'; // HourMinuteSec 1

      var p = new RegExp(re1+re2+re3+re4,["i"]);
      var m = p.exec(txt);
      if (m != null)
      {
          var ddmmyyyy1=m[1];
          var ws1=m[2];
          var time1=m[3];
          document.write("("+ddmmyyyy1.replace(/</,"&lt;")+")"+"("+ws1.replace(/</,"&lt;")+")"+"("+time1.replace(/</,"&lt;")+")"+"\n");
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give you what you want:

```
var date = "Thursday sep 20-2-2015 00:00:00 GMT (+5:00) Pakistan Standard Time";
var expectedDate = date.match(/\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/g);
```

Comment: Thanks alot!! If it doesn't trouble can you please explain a lil bit what does the expression do? i mean how it is trimming? Thanks.

Comment: @AhsanAbbas, here we are not trimming. We are finding the match with our expression. `\d` is for digits `[0-9]`. `\d{1,2}` says occurrence of digits, minimum 1, maximum 2. Then you have `-` symbols as in the string. `\s` is for white-space. `\d{4}` says, match exactly 4 occurrence. And the `/g` at last is for global matching.